# How to convert iptables-service rules into firewalld rules?

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I'm working on setting up vpnserver and I have IPTables rules that need to be converted to Firewalld rules

Enable nat and postrouting:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.7.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source [YOUR SERVER IP ADDRESS]

iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a necessity to use firewalld, however, there's a guide to help you migrate from iptables to firewalld followed by the [RHEL 6 --> RHEL 7 guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-security_and_access_control)

TL;DR - If you have configured your **system-config-firewall** after upgrading to CentOS 7 and installing firewalld, you can use the **firewall-cmd-offline** tool
to migrate the config in `/etc/sysconfig/system-config-firewall` into the default zone of firewalld `/etc/firewalld`

Other option would be to disable firewalld and continue to use the old iptables and ip6tables services. This would allow you to keep the existing firewall rules. Copy the `iptables-save` export and load it with iptables-restore.

**OR**

Just create a new configuration with firewall-cmd or firewall-config.

Comment: Infortunately i had problem with enable iptables , i installed but couldn't enable it with any commands like : `sudo systemctl enable iptables` `sudo systemctl start iptables` `'systemctl unmask iptables ` ---> responses are :`Failed to start iptables.service: Unit is masked` or `Failed to execute operation: Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown`